# Java SimpleDateFormat convert between timezones

Tags: java, datetime

I'm having trouble converting a timestamp returned from a MySQL server into a different timezone. The server's timezone is UTC.

```
DateFormat serverFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    try {
        Date timestamp = serverFormatter.parse("2017-05-06T20:50:59.000Z");
        SimpleDateFormat localFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
        localFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
        print (localFormat.format(timestamp));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The output is always `8:50 PM` and I'm expecting `1:50 PM` (the value returned from my Swift program's equivalent process.

Comment: I ran your program and it printed `"1:50 AM"` (after I changed `print` to `System.out.println` on the last line of the `try` block).

Comment: When I run code, I get "5:50 PM", because my timezone is `America/New_York`.

Comment: Oh dear, have I just given away my location?  What's that black car pulling up outside?

Comment: The [Answer by Andreas](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43948576/642706) is good and correct. But the bigger solution is to **use date-time objects** when conversing with your database for date-time values **rather than strings**. As of JDBC 4.2 and later, you can send/receive java.time objects via `PreparedStatement::setObject` and `ResultSet::getObject`. Search Stack Overflow for many examples and discussions. Your issues have already been asked and answered many times on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @BasilBourque I'm not accessing my MySQL data directly with my Java program, it's fetched via a REST api.

Comment: @JordanOsterberg Then why mention MySQL in your Question? Why add irrelevant distracting details? Please edit your Question to be about, well, your actual question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your *parsing* format string is incomplete, so you're not honoring the timezone giving in the input.

Change format string to `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"`.

---

**UPDATE**

Since your input string is [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, you can parse that using [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) (Java 8+), without having to give an input format.

Assuming your default [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) formats time like you want, you can then do it without specifying an explicit output format too.

```
// Prints "1:50 PM" (since my locale is "en_US")
System.out.println(Instant.parse("2017-05-06T20:50:59.000Z")
                          .atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"))
                          .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime(FormatStyle.SHORT)));
```

Comment: Yup, I just worked that out, and was just about to post it myself.  +1 for being too quick for me!

Comment: To be clear, this Answer is correct to be using the modern java.time classes. The Question uses the troublesome `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes that are now legacy and should be avoided.